# genymotion + SqLite database + android studio = не видно БД

Tags: java, android, sqlite, genymotion

В общем ситуация такова,юзаю Дженимоушн, в Андроид Студио через Девайс Монитор к базам не добраться, скрин прикрепил. ИХ просто не видно. Есть какой-то быстрый выход из ситуации?) Стандартный эмулятор совсем плох.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: боюсь по скрину не видно что вам мешает открыть папку вашего приложения и найти там файл с базой

Comment: по стандарту вместо папок CON должны идти имена проектов, вот как в левой части примерно. Я загуглил и действительно есть такая проблема с genymotion. Говорят что нужно шаманить над этим, рутить , думал может кто-то непосредственно тут сталкивался с этой проблемой, чтобы решить по быстрому, может другой эмулятор есть. Вы чем пользуетесь?

Comment: Посоветую иметь рутованый телефон на такие случаи.

Comment: @Romikromikromik эм, так у вас там и есть имена пакетов, вы просто колонку с именем расширьте что бы имена влазили)

Comment: @xkor , мне очень стыдно) простите)

Comment: Всем спасибо!!!